# issue with WPF datagrid

Tags: wpf

I am modifying the existing WPF code which displays data in data grid. The code logic goes like this, datatable will be created based on the data in database table. Then for all the columns in datatable, grid columns(six columns) will be created and binded to display the data. All the column types are DataGridTextColumn. There is a button to add new rows into the grid and save back to database. Everything is existing and working fine.

Now What i have to do is, i have to modify the code so that when the user clicks on add button the new row will be displayed but the new row should be displaying 
two columns(out of 6 columns) as combobox instead of textbox as it was doing before and the rest of save back to database will happen as it exists.

I have to do everything in code behind file and not in xaml.

But i am clueless to modify this code which will work as described above.

Any info will be really helpful .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, what have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: I am very new to WPF so finding difficult to modify the existing logic, and so any direction or sample to implement the above functionality in code behind file of wpf application will be helpful.

Comment: You need to define an edit template for the two columns that have dropdowns. And you really should do it in the XAML, doing it in the code behind is just.... wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. So i can have only edit template in xaml and leave the existing logic as it is in code behind which is currently populating data from table to data grid ? if so you have any samples for doing this . sorry for asking since i am new to wpf and breaking my head past few days for progressing on this.